Streaming video from guest to host QEMU
I have Linux on my computer.
Windows is installed in the QEMU virtual machine.
A webcam has been added to the virtual machine.
What is the best way to transfer an image from a virtual machine's webcam to the host machine?
Do I need to use a bridge?
I'm a little confused.
Thank you.
P.S. My host machine IP is 192.168.1.23/24.
I do translation in OBS on my guest machine udp://192.168.1.30:11000. And when I try to receive on host by udp://192.168.1.30:11000, there is nothing...

You definitely Dont’t need to use a bridge. Do you save the webcam footage to your local hard drives or backed up to your VM? You could try creating a local shared folder for your VM and use the clipboard feature to copy it to windows- or you could use piping tools like FFmpeg instead? Good luck anyway.

thx for answer. I need real time transferring.

Now worries- real time transferring is easy to set up and reliable
